# Alternative to this keyword for referencing class properties, inside a public method

Tags: javascript, oop

```
class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.getElementById('div1');
  }

  doSomethingOnClick() {
     console.log(this.div.textContent);
  }
}

const ui = new UI();

document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', ui.doSomethingOnClick);
// in this context, the this inside the doSomethingOnClick method refers to the element being clicked

ui.doSomethingOnClick();
// in this context, the this refers to the class
```

In this case, is there any straight forward way of accessing **this.div** inside the method, because I would like to access both the clicked element and the class properties inside that method ?

P.S. honestly, before writing this, I went through several big threads about classes and the this keyword, and couldn't find a solution for my particular use case.

Comment: There is really a ton of information about this in [How does the this keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/5459839) with more than one solution for your case, and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to define the `this` used for the call

```js
class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.getElementById('div1');
  }

  doSomethingOnClick() {
     console.log(this.div.textContent);
  }
}

const ui = new UI();

document.getElementById('button1')
  .addEventListener('click', ui.doSomethingOnClick.bind(ui));
```

```html
<div id="div1">content</div>
<button id="button1">hi</button>
```

---

with access to the event as asked in the comment

```js
class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.getElementById('div1');
  }

  // only need to add an argument here
  doSomethingOnClick(event) {
     console.log(event.target);
     console.log(this.div.textContent);
  }
}

const ui = new UI();

document.getElementById('button1')
  .addEventListener('click', ui.doSomethingOnClick.bind(ui) );
```

```html
<div id="div1">content</div>
<button id="button1">hi</button>
```

Comment: How would you go about accessing the clicked button inside the method, since the this keyword now refers to the class ?

Comment: I'd do `.addEventListener('click', e => ui.doSomethingOnClick.bind(ui)(e) )` and add the clickEvent as a parameter for `doSomethingOnClick`, I added a second snippet to the answer, take a look

Comment: made some tests and my previous comment overcomplicate things, look at the second snippets, way easier